# Sending ether to a contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

Beginner in solidity and i'm trying to send ether from an address to a contract. I've tried transferring ether using the Remix compiler test accounts.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract sendether{

     function receiveEther() payable public{
     }

     function sendEther(address _address) payable public{
         uint value = 5 ether;

         _address.transfer(value);
     }

}
```

I made a simple code to accept ether from an address and send ether to an address.

What i'm not sure is, if i made a Dapp, can i just send ether from my wallet and not execute the receiveEther() function. If no, how can i accept the ether from an address?

Comment: Note that the `sendEther` function doesn't look like it needs to be declared `payable`, but it does look like it needs some sort of access-restriction, because the way things stand as of now, anyone can call it and get 5 ether out of your contract!

Comment: is there a safer way to transfer ethers to an address?

Comment: Add a state variable `address owner`, a function `constructor() public {owner = msg.sender;}`, and a statement `require(msg.sender == owner);` at the beginning of the `sendEther` function. Thus, only the account used for deploying the contract will be able to invoke this function.

Answer (score 1):

First, the function should be payable.

Also, you don't need to have transfer or any other function to receive ETH.
Just check msg.value.

For example:

```
function receiveETH() payable public{
     uint value = 5 ether;

    require(msg.value >= value, "Insufficient ETH";
    // do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To accet ETH regardless of the function called you need a so-called **nameless fallback function**:

```
function () public payable {
}
```

Then whenever you send ETH to the contract this function will get called.

Comment: that means if i send ether from my wallet to the contract address, the contract will receive the ether? there's no need to add anything else on my DApp besides the fallback function?

Comment: Yes exactly. You should try it out first on a local testnet so you get a good grasp of the dynamics involved.

Comment: @ThomasVanderstraeten If you want explicitely call a function and send ether, then that function has to be payable. If function is invoked and the function exists the fallback function will be skipped entirely. You can invoke a function from a contract and pass ether with `myContrac.myFunction.value(1 ether)(myParam1, myParam2, ...)`.