# Send ETH to Contract Fails in Tests

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, sendtransaction

I'm trying to send ETH to a contract in tests using hardhat `await owner.sendTransaction({to: greeter.address, value: "1000000"})`, but it reverts with "function selector was not recognized" error.

You can reproduce this with a basic project -

```
npm init -y
npm i -D hardhat
npx hardhat # use defaults
```

edit `test/sample-test.js` and add the following test case -

```
  it("Should send ETH to the contract", async function () {
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, world!");
    await greeter.deployed();
    await owner.sendTransaction({to: greeter.address, value: "1000000"});
  });
```

run tests `npx hardhat test` and the newly added test will fail with `Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback nor receive function`.

Full test log -

```
Deploying a Greeter with greeting: Hello, world!
Changing greeting from 'Hello, world!' to 'Hola, mundo!'
    ✔ Should return the new greeting once it's changed (626ms)
Deploying a Greeter with greeting: Hello, world!
    1) Should send ETH to the contract


  1 passing (745ms)
  1 failing

  1) Greeter
       Should send ETH to the contract:
     Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback nor receive function
    at Greeter.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/Greeter.sol:6)
    at EthModule._estimateGasAction (/Users/tal/dev/solidity/SendEthToContract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:425:7)
    at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/Users/tal/dev/solidity/SendEthToContract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/Users/tal/dev/solidity/SendEthToContract/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Any idea how to send ETH to the contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** As pointed out by @Nergon, there's an [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity) that explains this phenomena.

To send ETH to a contract without using a `payable` function, it needs to have a function using special solidity keyword `receive` to allow receiving ETH without calling a function.

```
receive() external payable
```

---

Seems that a contract can receive ETH only through a `payable` function.

ETH receiving function should look something like this -

```
function receiveETH() public payable {
    // code
}
```

it can then receive ETH in tests using -

```
await farmer.receiveETH({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")});
```

Comment: While exploring your own options and posting an answer to yourself is definitely useful, maybe searching for answers before creating a question is better to improve the quality of the content in SO.

Comment: Now as to your question and answer, [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity) answer explains how to properly receive eth in your contract.

Comment: I have searched for a few hours and couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Also, I'm quite familiar with SO, they have other exchanges so don't rely on the ethereum exchange score to assume I don't know how to produce quality content.

Comment: Checking the answer you've linked, it does help but the question asks "What is the receive keyword in solidity?", unless I'm already familiar with the concept it would be hard to find it; which explains why I didn't find it. Thus, adding a question to SO that rephrases the question is very helpful to the community, hopefully save some time to others.

Comment: Given that you asked and a moment later you answered your own question, allow me to disagree. Also the answer i've posted took less than a minute to find.

Comment: For the record, I googled "receive ether solidity".

Comment: That proves my point. I didn't know about the "receive" keyword. I searched for "send ETH to contract". As for your other concern, the reason why I posted this question+answer is **because** I did search for hours and couldn't find anything that answers this question in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135910/discussion-between-kof-and-nergon).

Comment: Receive is an english term. Just change "Any idea how to send ETH to the contract?" to "Any idea how to receive ETH in a contract?".

Comment: You're just proving why SO needs this question, using other commonly used keywords that previously didn't appear in Google's search results.

Comment: Yes. Your question will now also appear along with [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/61426/99097), [that one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15953/99097), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71051955/3408204), and a few more thousands. If this community of SO was as moderated as more popular ones, this question would have been closed as a duplicate in a matter of seconds. Enjoy the rest of your day friend.

Comment: During my searches I saw the answers you've posted and none of them solve the issue I was facing. In my case sending ETH failed only in tests, as the contract doesn't have any payable functions and shouldn't have. None of these answers explained the `receive` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled into this question while writing a test on a forked hardhat network, where I wanted to send ETH to a 3rd party contract that doesn't have a receive function or a payable fallback function. I needed this because I then wanted to impersonate the contract to call a permissioned method on another contract that only accepts calls from the first contract.

In case anyone is in the same situation, I'll share my solution using the [hardhat_setBalance RPC method](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setbalance), through hardhat-network-helpers library. This can set any balance arbitrarily.

```
import * as helpers from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";

// ...

await helpers.setBalance(MyContract.address, hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1"));
```